# Does anyone know why this audio won't work in FireFox?

Tags: html, firefox, audio

I've been searching and simplified this down to only what is causing the problem.

```
<audio id="SoundHandle" style="display:none" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    SoundHandle = document.getElementById('SoundHandle');
    SoundHandle.src = 'test.ogg';
    SoundHandle.play();
</script>
```

The above code works fine in Chrome, and when I still had appropriate checks and such, it worked for an MP3 in IE 9. But in FireFox it simply doesn't play a sound, also when I changed it to being in this layout, I put it at the top of the page. In Firefox now, on top of not playing the sound, nothing below the script tags gets rendered to the page.

Does anyone know anything about this?

Comment: me also .audio work in chrome but in firefox notworking very strange

Comment: if you go to [demo working in firefox](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_audio_all) but if you copy the code to your editor it desnot working. i try to run mp3 it doesnot support but may be ogg it will support.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

There are a few JS-specific things which could be going on, here, and a few server-specific things which could be going on, as well.

To get around all of the above, try this, first.

```
<audio id="player" controls>
    <source src="test.ogg" type='audio/ogg; codecs="vorbis"'>
</audio>
```

See if that solves your playing problem.
If it does, then you're likely dealing with JavaScript issues.

But if that player doesn't let you play audio at all, even though it's 100% HTML, then you're looking at server problems.

There are two culprits.  The first is the MIME type.
MIME types are the first part of what you see in the "type" attribute in that source element.

They tell a program how they should be reading the data inside the file.
In the old-days, you'd see that in CSS (type="text/css") or JS (type="text/javascript").

For those things, it doesn't matter at all -- your browser knows what to do with CSS and what to do with JS, they're kind of a big deal.

FireFox *requires* that your server be set up to serve .ogg/.oga/.ogv files with the proper MIME types.
ie: FF needs to know to treat them like OGG files and not like text files.

Have a look here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Configuring_servers_for_Ogg_media

That should be your starting point for debugging.
After that, we can talk JavaScript.

The reason that it works in Chrome is because Chrome works some magic to guess that it's an .ogg file, even though the server is suggesting that it's a "text/html" file.

Answer (score 0):

my freind it is working:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    var mediaElement = document.getElementById("myMediaElementID");
    mediaElement.pause();
    mediaElement.src = "";
</script>
</head>
<body>
<audio id="demo" src="song.ogg"></audio>

<div>
  <button onclick="document.getElementById('demo').play()">Play the Audio</button>
  <button onclick="document.getElementById('demo').pause()">Pause the Audio</button>
  <button onclick="document.getElementById('demo').volume+=0.1">Increase Volume</button>
  <button onclick="document.getElementById('demo').volume-=0.1">Decrease Volume</button>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```